# Oculus hand tracking not working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, tracking, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm trying to use the hand tracking feature of Oculus Quest 2 to create a serious game.
The development environment is Unity. However, no matter what I try, hand tracking doesn't work.

The controller moves, but it just can't track my "hand." I tried various methods for two nights, and not only the Oculus integration tool but also the OPEN XR toolkit failed.

I have tried everything in this link
[text](https://www.getdroidtips.com/oculus-quest-2-hand-tracking-not-working/)

including changing the computer and using other Oculus devices such as Quest Pro.

The only thing I haven't tried is running it on Windows 10. Does Windows 11 not support hand tracking as it used to?

If anyone can help me, please help! I have tried everything on the internet and the Meta developer forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding that your hands are not being tracked in the virtual environment it could be that you have not enabled hand tracking within the Oculus Quest 2 itself.

For that, put on your Quest 2, go into Settings -> "Movement Tracking" and enable the toggle next to "Hand and Body tracking".